# Finding total number of lists and elements from a text file with list of lists structure and empty lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to compute the total number of lists and total number of elements of a text file. The text file `try1.txt` consists of a list of lists structure like this:

```
[[], ['i', 'am', 'a', 'good', 'boy'], ['i', 'am', 'an', 'engineer']]
```

```
import ast
global inputList
inputList = []
path = "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/folder/"
def read_data():
    for file in ['try1.txt']:
        with open(path + file, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as infile:
           inputList.extend(ast.literal_eval(*infile.readlines()))
    print(len(inputList))
    print(sum(len(x) for x in inputList))
read_data()
```

The output for the above mentioned input list should be: 3 and 9.

I have tried but I am getting error when there is a empty list. Is there any way to solve the issue? If not then I want to display the output by removing the empty lists; in that case the output should be 2 and 9.

If I remove the empty list, then I am getting the output as 2 and 9. But the inclusion of empty list creating problem. The error I am getting:

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Subscript object at 0x0000020E99CC0088>
```

Comment: Fixing the missing comma, `sum(len(x) for x in [[], ['i', 'am', 'a', 'good', 'boy'], ['i', 'am', 'an', 'engineer']]) == 9`, as expected. Please give a [mcve] to explain the actual problem -- *what* error, for example?

Comment: could you simply count the number of [ and ' ?

Comment: @ArcoBast. I need to count the total number of lists (including and excluding the empty lists) and its total elements.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. Kindly see my edit.

Comment: Ah, so the missing comma is actually in your data; the [mcve] is `ast.literal_eval("[[], ['i', 'am', 'a', 'good', 'boy']['i', 'am', 'an', 'engineer']]")`. Where is the file coming from? You should fix this upstream.

Comment: Got it. My bad. I missed the comma. Now its okay. Please check @jonrsharpe

Comment: Then do you still have a question? If not, please delete this post.

Comment: Yes I am unable to solve this if the list is having a empty list. I have shown the error above. Do check.

Comment: @see-king_of_knowledge note they already have `len(inputList)` in their question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes. Everything working fine, if and only if, there are no empty lists in the input list. The addition of empty lists creating errors which I have shown above.

Comment: No, you haven't. What you've posted is fine; `ast.literal_eval("[[], ['i', 'am', 'a', 'good', 'boy'], ['i', 'am', 'an', 'engineer']]")` gives `[[], ['i', 'am', 'a', 'good', 'boy'], ['i', 'am', 'an', 'engineer']]`, without `ValueError`, on which both `len(inputList)` and `sum(len(x) for x in inputList)` work just fine, giving the expected values of `3` and `9` respectively. You may still have a problem, but **it's impossible to tell what it is from what you've posted**.

Comment: Also note you could just do `inputList = ast.literal_eval(infile.read())`. You don't need to predefine an empty list then extend it, or read lines into a list then splat the single item into `literal_eval`.

Comment: don't you think, the total number of lists, elements and empty lists could be inferred from counts of `[` `'` and `[]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe if you copy and paste his code, the problem will occur. The problem is not on literal_eval. It's on readlines() that inserts a line feed. that line feed is the nature of his error.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was not the empty list! It's the LF at the end of the string.

This code work on python 3.6:

```
import ast
v = ast.literal_eval("[[],['i', 'am', 'a', 'good', 'boy'],['i', 'am', 'an', 'engineer']]")`
```

If the error persists on a older version and python upgrade is not a option, just remove the empty list before evaluate the expression:

```
exp = infile.read()
empty_count = exp.count('[]')
exp = exp.replace('[],','')
inputList.extend(ast.literal_eval(*exp))
print('List Count:%d' % len(inputList)+empty_count)
```